Family of vector spaces over a scheme
In Example 2.12 of the notes by Victoria Hoskins, the concept of a naive moduli problem is introduced, focusing on vector bundles (locally free sheaves) on a fixed scheme ( X ) up to isomorphism. The extension of this moduli problem introduces families over a scheme ( S ) using locally free sheaves over ( $X \times S$ ) flat over ( S ). However, two different equivalence relations are proposed:

The equivalence relation $\( F \sim_0 G \)$ defined as $\( F \cong G \)$ for locally free sheaves $\( F \)$ and $\( G \)$ over $\( X \times S \)$.
The equivalence relation $\( F \sim_S G \) $defined as $ \( F \cong G \otimes \pi_S^* L \)$ for locally free sheaves $\( F \)$ and $\( G \)$ over $\( X \times S \)$ and a line bundle $\( L \rightarrow S \)$, where $\( \pi_S : X \times S \rightarrow S \)$.

My question pertains to the clarity regarding how these relations define an equivalence relation. Specifically, it seems to me that the parameter space ( S ) should somehow parametrize the family of objects in both cases. However, this aspect is not entirely clear to me from the provided explanation. Could someone elaborate on how these families are defined over ( S ), as I may have misunderstood a crucial aspect of the construction?
